# Unity & VS Code - Can't build, can't debug

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I was trying to switch to VS Code. Not a success so far. I can't build in VS Code. And I can't debug. I want to be able to give a build command in VS Code to build to solution, so that I don't have to wait for and switch to Unity each time I update a script. And then switch back to VS Code. I know that VS Code is "just an editor", but would like to be able to test build.

And I can't get the debugger to work; the page, at github: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/vscode-unity-debug,  talks about opening a debug view, this icon, the bug at the bottom;

[image: Guide picture]

Mine looks like this

[image: My Picture]

I don't have the debug view. I don't know why. I've installed the C# packages, SDK and Unity debugger extension. Just not there.

I am kinda stuck here. I mean I liked VS Code for a bit of editing, but if I can't build or debug, it's not useful to me. I am probably missing something blatantly obvious. But don't know what.

Comment: In the Unity editor, you can trigger 'debug mode' which is helpful. In the upper right-hand corner of the inspector window. Also, I used VS Code in the past- did not like it. If game dev is something you really want to use. I would switch to JetBrains Rider IDE - Its life-changing.

Comment: I tried Rider for over a year. Never landed for me. Also, for non-commercial use, I think it's rather expensive.